# String.Compare() with Hungarian CultureInfo works not correct for specific strings

Tags: c#

String.Compare() with Hungarian CultureInfo works not correct for specific strings:

```
if (0 == String.Compare(@"ny", @"nY", true, new CultureInfo("hu-HU")))
  Console.WriteLine("Equal");
else
  Console.WriteLine("Not equal");
```

Of course I suppose to get "Equal" answer, but it's not.
If I change the string it works properly (for example for "abc" and "ABC" it prints "Equal")
It seems a problem with specific symbols.

Comment: mmm... what is the result and what did you expect ?

Comment: @MBen Actually it doesn't, that's the OP's question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_alphabet It appears Ny is a letter... Maybe a Hungarian could answer you better than me... Io Napot!

Comment: @Kek `Ny` isn't what the OP is trying to compare, it's `ny` & `nY` which in Hungarian translate to the same word (according to Google Translate that is) - `nY` translates to `NY`.

Comment: @James To expand on @Kek's comment: `ny` is considered a letter (lowercase `Ny`), and `nY` is considered two letters, so they don't compare equal. I don't know any Hungarian, so I don't know if this is correct, I'm just saying this appears to be the logic used by `String.Compare`.

Comment: @hvd yeah that's probably it, I looked at some example alphabets and `nY` doesn't exist. So basically the reason it's failing is because they are indeed 2 different strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What would you expect? In Hungarian, "ny" is considered **one** letter. It can be written like "ny", "Ny", or "NY". But never "nY". This works as expected:

```
  var hu = new CultureInfo("hu-HU");
  Console.WriteLine(String.Compare("Ny", "NY", true, hu));
  Console.WriteLine(String.Compare("ny", "NY", true, hu));
  Console.WriteLine(String.Compare("ny", "Ny", true, hu));
```

In Hungarian, they don't have a letter "y" except in foreign words and some names. But when you say `"nY"`, there's no possibility that this could be the "ny" letter. So maybe .NET treats it as **two** letters.

Does anyone know Hungarian language well? It could be interesting to hear their opinion. But I'm pretty sure the string "nY" could never appear in "natural" Hungarian.

Comment: I am Hungarian, and you are right. We have letters "n", "ny", and "y" separately. "y" is quite rare as you said before. "ny" letter consists of two sounds, the "n" and "y" - don't think too much about the logics. In these cases only the first sound can be in capital, like "Ny", never "NY", or "nY". Some other cases: "Sz", "Ty", etc. Also "n", and "ny" are considered different letters. The standard English letters are first then the special hungarian letters come. Example: a, á, e, é, n, ny, t, ty, o, ó, ö, ő ...